# GTK GUIs have stopped appearing

Tags: python, gtk

From some reason, all my GTK GUIs have suddenly stopped appearing. It happens both inside Geany and when I simply execute a script from the command line. There is no output. Python scripts that don't use GTK operate normally. I have determined that even in the following simple example, the Application object never fires its do_startup signal. What could cause it not to fire?

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk, Gdk
import sys


class MainBrowser(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainBrowser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_default_size(400, 400)
        self.show_all()

class Application(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Application, self).__init__(*args, application_id="org.example.myapp", **kwargs)
        self.window = None

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        if not self.window:
            self.window = MainBrowser(application=self, title="Title")
        self.window.present()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.run(sys.argv)
```

Comment: code works for me on Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.7.4. You could add `print()` to see which part is working. The only idea: maybe somewhere on disk is information that previous version is still running so new instance doesn't create new window.

Comment: When I put a print statement in the Application __init__ function, it prints, but when I put one in do_startup or do_activate, it does not print. I allso wondered about some sort of corruption on the disk, so I tried the same code on two computers and it executes on neither. I even tried copying and pasting code into new text files and getting rid of the .pyc files and that didn't help, either.

Comment: UPDATE: The one thing that does work is to comment out the main loop and Application class and replace it with a simple: win = MainBrowser()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main(). So something is up with Gtk.Application. I'm really only using it for a couple Gio.SimpleActions that are not essential, but I'm still in the dark as to what changed.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer ?

Comment: Yes, restarting didn't help.